# How to hide symbols in c++ static library?

Tags: c++, gcc, ld

I will modulate the situation.
In this question I use Ubuntu 16.04 with GCC 6.5.0 and CMake 3.13.2.

I have 4 static libs and one executable: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `main`.
`A` have `int add(int, int)` that just add 2 given ints. `B` have `int addb(int, int)` that just call `add` from `A`.
`C` have `int add(int, int)` that multiplies 2 given ints.
`D` have `void print()` that call `addb` from `B` and `add` from `C`.
And `main` just calls `print()`.
All of this functions splits declaration and definition into `.cpp` and `.hpp`.

Scheme:

```
A (add)
  |
B (addb)    C (add)
  |           |
  |___________|
        |
      D (print)
        |
       main
```

What I must do to hide `add` from `A` symbol? Because I have multiply definition from ld, when linking `main`.

If I just build with cmake, it will call `add` from `C` in two cases (see `print()` from `D`). I link `B` with ld (`ld -static`), but now I have two issues:

- multiply definition of `add` (first defined in `A`)
- `no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created`

Also, I tried to make `A` and `C` `SHARED` with cmake, but it call `add` from `C` just like before.

I excepted that B will be "full" static lib, with no `*UND*` and if I call `addb` it will call `add` from `A`, `add` will call from `C`.
Thank you!

Comment: This cannot be done. You must use unique symbol names, to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: This is the exact reason why you want to use namespaces in C++. If multiple libraries output the same (mangled) symbol names because they don't use different namespaces then you're out of luck.

Comment: You're not allowed to break the [one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule). Each symbol must be defined only *once*. The typical solution with C++ and libraries is to use either classes or namespaces. Then you can have e.g `namespace A { int add(int, int); }` and `namespace C { int add(int, int); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are violating the one [definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule). What this says, put shortly, is that each function<sup>(1)</sup> must be defined only once (unless declared as inline, in which case all definitions must be the same).

What you are trying to do is idiomatically done with namespaces. Your A,B,C libraries would declare all of their functions in an appropriate namespaces.

Something like

```
namespace A
{
   int add(int lhs, int rhs);
};

namespace C
{
   int add(int lhs, int rhs);
}
```

(1) The one definition rule is not only about functions. On the program level, it applies to variables as well, and within a given translation unit, this is extended to templates, class types and enums as well.